# ssh warning message

Tags: python, shell, ssh

Is there a way to avoid ssh login warning messages while login to remote server through scripts? 
 But I do not want to change any configurations in remote server, but in scripts or any options.

Comment: `ssh -q` or `ssh -q -q`doesn't work for you?

Comment: What's Python's role in this? Could you be more specific?

Comment: trying to have a automated ssh login scripts in python,but I do not want to capture the ssh warning messages displayed while login into remote machine.

Comment: Is fixing the cause of the warning message not the better approach? What warning message is it exactly?

Comment: No, Actually that is going to be a security warning messages displayed from remote machines.That is needed from remote machine perspective, but I do not want to capture while login through ssh through my python scripts.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to suppress warnings coming from the `ssh` command, you can use the ssh options:

```
-o 'CheckHostIP no' -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -o 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null'
```

when connecting to test systems that are regularly being reinstalled. This does yield the following warning:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'hostname' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

But if you add the `-q` option, this warning goes away also.

**Yes** This is horribly dangerous WRT man-in-the-middle attacks, but it is ideal for what we're doing

If you're trying to suppress warnings from the remote system then if it obeys the .hushlogin mechanism, you can use:

```
touch .hushlogin
```

on the remote system to suppress the `motd` (message of the day - which is regularly where the warning messages appear).

Comment: Absolutely 100% agree on bypassing the warnings being a horrible idea.  This option should ONLY be used when you are on an internal network with the server in question.  Never ever ever over the public internet.

Answer (score 1):

Call ssh with the argument:

```
bash -i
```

for example:

```
/usr/bin/ssh root@10.8.13.59 "bash -i"
```

It will supress message from the server